# Does Chef has push-jobs for AIX OS?

Tags: chef-infra

I am new to Chef and want to know if push-jobs client is there for AIX operating system?
I know Chef supports AIX now, but does anyone has idea whether push-jobs client can be installed on AIX?

Answer (score 0):

The push jobs agent is a Ruby program like chef-client, so if you can run chef-client then you can run push jobs.